# Why does this change in If-else statement introduce "'global_variable' is assigned to before global declaration" SyntaxError?

Tags: python, syntax-error, global-variables

I am fairly new to Python and would be very thankful for any explanation on this:

I have a question about how and why the compiler behaves strangely (in my opinion) in case of declaring global variables using keyword **global** in different scopes

When I run this piece of code it works perfectly fine:

```
global_variable = 0


def change_global(condition):
    global global_variable
    if condition:
        global_variable = 1
    else:
        global_variable = 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(global_variable)
    change_global(True)
    print(global_variable)
    change_global(False)
    print(global_variable)

Output:
0
1
2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But if I do the same but split the declaration for each case of **condition** value:

```
global_variable = 0


def change_global(condition):
    if condition:
        global global_variable
        global_variable = 1
    else:
        global global_variable
        global_variable = 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(global_variable)
    change_global(True)
    print(global_variable)
    change_global(False)
    print(global_variable)
```

I get the

```
global global_variable
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: name 'global_variable' is assigned to before global declaration
```

Is it caused by compiler preemptively trying to avoid errors?

Because, as I understand, during the execution there will never be any problem like declaring **global_variable** as **global** twice

Or am I missing something here?

Edit:

This works fine as well, even though I changed the order of conditions meeting and declared variable as **global** only in the first one

```
global_variable = 0


def change_global(condition):
    if condition:
        global global_variable
        global_variable = 1
    else:
        global_variable = 2



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(global_variable)
    change_global(False)
    print(global_variable)
    change_global(True)
    print(global_variable)

Output:
0
2
1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Is it because the If statements do not introduce new scopes? If I move "global" declaration to the "else" part or below of "if,else" statement I get the error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global-stmt):

> Names listed in a `global` statement must not be used in the same code block textually preceding that `global` statement.

You have a `global global_variable` statement in the `else:` block. You use the variable in the `if` block, which precedes that declaration. The fact that there's another `global` declaration for the same variable before this doesn't matter, each one is checked independently. You can see the same thing more simply with:

```
def change_global():
    global foo
    foo = 1
    global foo
```

This will report the same syntax error.

Putting the declaration in the `if` or `else` block doesn't restrict its interpretation. `global` declarations don't have to be executed, they're processed at compile time and apply to the entire function definition.